# Are there any ways to rotate an element aside from CSS transforms?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I am having some animation issues that I've determined are caused by overloaded CSS Transitions (or a slow computer) on Chrome.

I'm curious if there are any alternatives to CSS Transforms to rotate elements? (I am simulating a watch dial rotating based on scroll position.)

Comment: Can you recreate the code in a jsfiddle? It's hard to tell just from your description, you may be using JS that is not good performance wise.

Comment: Have you GPU accelerated the element(s)? Showing code is kind of a necessity when asking questions here.

Comment: I guess another way to frame this question is: are there any alternatives to CSS transforms to rotate an element?

Comment: Short answer: no, transforms are the only way to rotate an element.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do rotation with html elements. Only with css transforms, you will accomplish this.
What you can try to add more performance is to use rotate3d **to activate hardware acceleration**.

Example:

```
transform: rotate(30deg); // 2d rotate
transform: rotateZ(30deg); // 3d rotate
```

You can check more info on 3d transforms in this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-css3-2d-and-3d-transform-techniques/